# What are the best option for French sliding door blinds

Tags: blinds, sliding-glass-door

[regular honeycomb blind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiEu2.jpg)[image]

[[image: Sliding door with a big door handle]

We are thinking to place the blind bracket outside the French sliding doors. My other blinds are all honeycomb blinds.  I am wondering what are the best blind option we can have on French sliding doors to match other honeycomb blinds in the house.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I hung curtains. Insulated ones, because that expanse of glass and lousy seals is a problem for both heating and cooling. If youbown the place, condider replacing them with french doors at some point.

Answer (score 1):

kelsham PlyGem Freedom 800 Clad French Sliders are amazing!!!!  French Sliders aren't regular sliding glass doors... They're expensive but WELL worth it!!

Dave I too have honeycomb throughout and just replaced all 4 of my French patio doors with the Freedom 800-I've had a set for 14 years and no issues!!!  I'm looking at room darkening generic Vertiglide blinds.

Here's the link..
http://www.blindsgalore.com/m/product/253981/bali-diamondcell-verticell-shades-blackout-midnight-and-legacy?siz.height=48&siz.width=48&utm_medium=shoppingfeed&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=googleshoppingfeed&gclid=CjwKEAiAh560BRDu-aD93r-J_zoSJACrxZG2gn460CjxGR51HMgBhA2qoAFkpoFb-uHvxwUHmHKxFxoCpKTw_wcB